# Converting a for loop into a while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I've done a for loop that returns true if there is a 2 next to another 2 and now I'm trying to do it using a while loop. I can't seem to make my while loop to work.

Here's the for loop I've done

```
def has22(nums):
    "Return true if array contains a 2 next to a 2 somewhere"""
    for i in range(0, len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i] == 2 and nums[i+1] == 2:
            return True    
    return False
```

I tried running this while loop but it doesn't work.

```
def has22(nums):
    """While loop version"""
    i = 0
    while i < len(nums) - 1:
        if nums[i] == 2 and nums[i+1] == 2:
        return True
        i += 1
```

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

1. The `return True` is not indented, so it's always returned (ie. it is not the body of the `if` statement)
2. The function never returns `False

Try:

```
def has22(nums):
    """While loop version"""
    i = 0
    while i < len(nums) - 1:
        if nums[i] == 2 and nums[i+1] == 2:
            return True
        i += 1
    return False
```

Comment: `i += 1` is in the body of the while loop: you want it to be run on every iteration of the loop, not just when the `if` condition is True